# How to check if an algebra is not an Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, hopf-algebras

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a $k$-algebra. Are there known techniques  to check that $A$ does not admit a structure of Hopf algebra? In particular if $H$ is a Hopf $k$-algebra and $M$ an $H$-bimodule, do you see any technique to check if the trivial extension algebra $H\ltimes M$ does not admit a structure of Hopf algebra?

The trivial extension $H\ltimes M$ is $H\oplus M$ as $H$-bimodules and the algebra product is defined by $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bc+ad)$.

As a start we can assume that $H$ is a tensor algebra and $M$ is its dual with the canonical bimodule structure.

Comment: Completely unhelpful comment, but, being a crude American, I've always had trouble with using "an" before the letter H, and "an Hopf algebra" is one of the most awkward examples I've ever seen.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. What is meant by the trivial extension algebra? The notation $H\rtimes M$ suggest the  Radford-Majid bosonization (or biproduct), but for this to be a bialgebra one needs $M$ to be a bialgebra object in the category of $H$-modules (which then requires $H$ to be quasitriangular.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bc+ad)$? I think in this full general is very hard (impossible) to check if the extension $H\ltimes M$ does not admit a Hopf algebra structure. If there are more restrictions on the setting, like wanting $H$ to be a Hopf-subalgebra, giving a concrete $H$, then maybe.

Comment: yeah that was a typo. What if H is a tensor algebra?

Comment: One does not often show that something is not a Hopf algebra :-) Do you have a specific example (or family of examples) in mind? It will probably be easier to help you if you ask a more concrete question.

Comment: @MattSamuel, probably the OP' first language is a latin one: our h's are mostly mute so we tend to use "an" before words which start with an H even in English.

Comment: If you want a more concrete example I guess we could try with H being a tensor algebra and M being the (graded) $k$-dual with the natural bimodule structure, is that an Hopf algebra?

Comment: @Mariano in British English it's correct that way in at least some cases (an history for example; I don't know the rules). Americans may or may not do it, but many, including myself, never do.

Comment: @user271828, edit the question and add that there.